# Jquery Mobile Filter system, can't hide multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, filter

I'm making a Jquery Mobile app and have a page with 15 or so divs with class', I'm trying to make a filtering system so that when you press a button some of these divs disappear depending on the class. There are 3 groups and they all have an "all" class to display everything making 4 classes total.

Unfortunately most of the js I use never works even if I set up a jsfiddle for jquery mobile when I put it into my app it doesn't seem to work.

I wanted to use

```
function show(target) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(target).style.display = 'block';
    }
function hide(target) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(target).style.display = 'none';
    }
```

But that doesn't work whereas `document.getElementById` seems to work fine. However obviously I can only hide/show 1 div per button..

I was wondering if there was a work around for this or something completely different I should try?

Here's a jsfiddle of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/tzcx7gky/
It's completely broken in jsfiddle but it works fine in my code, which is odd..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need seperate `hide` - `show` functions. The following would take care of all.

```
$('a').on("click",function()
{
   $("#scroll_content div").hide(); // initially hide all divs inside the element with id = scroll_content
   var target = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); // find the class you wish to show using the text of the a tag clicked ( I would prefer using data-attr in this case but I'll leave the choice upto you.
     $("." + target).show(); // show the element with the class target.
});
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/tzcx7gky/2/

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly how I wanted it. However it doesn't seem to work in my code only in the jsfiddle, Could I have a different version possibly? [Here's](https://i.gyazo.com/b17d28718fafcff72bb40176019e9137.png) all the files I have in my js if it helps to identify the version..

Comment: You are probably missing document.ready to define the event delegation. http://jsfiddle.net/tzcx7gky/7/

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements. So you would have to itterate over the array and then set the display property on each one. Since you are already using jQuery you can use it to do it for all the elements.

```
function show(target) {
    /* jQuery uses CSS selectors to grab elements
       so we have to prefix the target with "."
       Alternativley we could pass in the whole selector in the
       function so we don't have to prefix it e.g.
       show('.all')
       $(target).show();
    */
    $("."+target).show();
}
function hide(target) {
    $("."+target).hide();
}
```

Here is the same implementation in the vanilla js framework

```
function show(target) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(target);
    elements.forEach(function(element){element.style.display = 'block';});
    }
function hide(target) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(target);
    elements.forEach(function(element){element.style.display = 'none';});
    }
```

note that `getElementById` returns a single element since id's are unique and there should only be one element with one id on the page. That is why it was working for you.